# How to find the pages that links to a specific page?

Tags: search, google-search, links, web-crawler

I have the following page

http://www.fda.gov/downloads/scienceresearch/fieldscience/laboratorymanual/ucm092156.pdf

I would like to find the pages on www.fda.gov that links to this page? How can I do that?

Comment: What do mean by _links to this page_?  Places on the FDA website that point to that particular link?

Comment: Places on the FDA website that point to that particular link, yes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding pages on a webpage that contain a certain link](http://superuser.com/questions/1034567/finding-pages-on-a-webpage-that-contain-a-certain-link)

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use `wget` to recursively download the entire website:

   `wget --recursive --page-requisites --html-extension --no-parent --domains
   www.fda.gov www.fda.gov`
2. You can then use `egrep` to recursively search through all the files to find which pages link to ucm092156.pdf:

   `egrep -r -o '*ucm092156.pdf' www.fda.gov/`

Comment: I have mac and windows.. no Linux

Comment: Using homebrew to get wget ..

Comment: Please note, web admins may not take kindly to you scraping their site, particularly if you have a high bandwidth connection. It is entirely possible that your IP address may be blacklisted. You may want to also include the `--limit-rate` flag to reduce the chances of that happening. For example, `--limit-rate=100k` will reduce your download speed to 100KB/sec

Comment: and you tell me this now... it's scraping the site as we speak

Comment: BTW I found that `grep -rl '*ucm092156.pdf' www.fda.gov/` on mac does the same job. (still waiting for it to finish the download, but looks good so far)

Comment: is there a way to only scrape `.html` files? It seems to download it all - including `.pdf` files

Comment: Sort of. You can Accept or Reject certain files, however that process occurs after the file has been downloaded. For example, to only _keep_ htm files: `-A '*.htm'`